# Is 'the most effective method to developing' correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "the most effective method *to developing* and improving health is daily exercise".

Here to+gerund structure seems like to be combined wrongly as preposition "to" doesn't belong to "method". So what do you think about that?

Comment: What preposition do you think might be better? Or what alternative structure do you think works better?

Comment: out of subject bu of course "in".

Comment: Does your feeling change, Cavid, when you eliminate "to developing and" from the sentence? Would you say "method to improving health"?

Comment: *In* works, as does *of*. Meanwhile *to* may not be my first or second choice, but it doesn't sound terrible.

Comment: I see you, without "to developing and "  it sounds more easy going but my focus here is "to + V ing" structure. It doesnt look grammatically fine for me

Comment: To me, "for" is the best choice.

Comment: Upon second look, "to developing and (to) improving" is a compound object (using gerunds, which are nouns) in an adjective prepositional phrase modifying *method.* It answers the question, like a single word adjective would ask, "*What kind*?" What kind of method? One the develops and improves health. A prepositional phrase can be of two kinds: an adjective which modifies a noun or pronoun (**method** = noun) or it can be an adverb prepositional phrase, acting like a one word adverb to modify an adjective, verb, or another adverb. http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/prepositionalphrase.htm

Comment: You may omit the second preposition (to) because of parallel construction which allows it. "to developing and (to) improving" = "to developing and improving" Parallel Construction is another topic for another time, but I'll reference: "16c. In parallel construction repeat an article, a preposition, or a pronoun whenever necessary to make the meaning clear."—John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Fifth Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 306.

Comment: Here's your Simple Sentence diagrammed: the | most | effective | method | to developing and improving health | is | daily | exercise = article | adverb modifying "effective" | adjective "effective" modifying *method* (*method = subject) | adjective prepositional phrase modifying *method* | verb | adjective | predicate nominative *exercise* which is a noun after the linking verb "is" to identify and/or explain the subject *method.* All terms used can be referenced here: http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/AL/HooverCity/SpainParkHigh/Uploads/Forms/Start%20Holt%20Handbook%2010.pdf

Answer (score 15):

When you use **to** to mean "for the purpose of," then you have to use the infinitive form of the verb, *not* the gerund.

> The most effective method **to** *develop* and *improve* health is daily exercise.

If you want to use the -ing form of the verb, then you need to use the preposition **for** or **of**.

> The most effective method **for** *developing* and *improving* health is daily exercise.
>
> The most effective method **of** *developing* and *improving* health is daily exercise.

Answer (score 5):

It's not incorrect.

*To* can mean *toward*.  You can say "method to X" to mean "method that is used to move toward goal/desired state X"

Comment: You wouldn't use method in that case though - you might say something like "The *fastest path* to improving health and increased vigor is daily exercise." Even that sounds off - we don't normally refer to "improving health" as a state, we usually say "improved health" or something similar.

Comment: I think "not incorrect" is about the right level of damning this sentence with faint praise. I might lean a little more towards "not unintelligible" though, for fear of encouraging it ;-)

Comment: could you give examples including "method to" to mean "toward" ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy rule.  It depends on the noun choice, e.g. *method, way, recipe, spell*. The noun governs what can follow.

It's an alchemical *method to make* gold from straw and dung.
It's an alchemical *way to make* gold from straw and dung.
It's an alchemical *recipe to make* gold from straw and dung.
It's a magical *spell to make* gold from straw and dung.

It's an alchemical *method of making* gold from straw and dung.   <sup>marginal</sup>
It's an alchemical *way of making* gold from straw and dung.
It's an alchemical *recipe of making* gold from straw and dung. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
It's a magical *spell of making* gold from straw and dung.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

It's an alchemical *method for making* gold from straw and dung.
It's an alchemical *way for making* gold from straw and dung. <sup>marginal</sup>
It's an alchemical *recipe for making* gold from straw and dung.
It's a magical *spell for making* gold from straw and dung.